# How to get rid of an automatically generated span via CSS (un-display)?

Tags: css, html

I am using the Drupal `ShareThis` module. Unfortunately, a recent security release of this module has added a `span` in the generated code and it disrupts the layout of my page major. Everything was working fine before.

There is no option to control the generation of this code:

```
<span class="chicklets twitter">&nbsp;</span>
```

Is it possible to remove/not display this span code via CSS? If yes how?

I tried:

```
.chicklets twitter {
    display:none;
}
```

but no success. I am not a CSS expert. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is a screen shot from FireBug:

[image]

I have been trying the suggested solutions:

```
span.chicklets {
    display:none;
}
```

The above completely removes all ShareThis buttons (which can be explained by the following issue):

```
span.chicklets.twitter {
    display:none;
}
```

The above removes the button, but the corresponding span still appears in FireBug as shadowed (see next).

[image]

Of course, I need to keep my button. What could cause this?

P.S.: Nevermind, I'll discuss this extra issue in another question if necessary.

Comment: you would want to use `span.chicklets.twitter{display:none;}`

Comment: what youve done is specified all twitter tags in the node with a class 'chicklets' haha

Comment: I tried to use span.chicklets.twitter{display:none;} but it deleted the button icon (see question update)

Comment: its possible that the span itself is conserving the space for the button, and when its not present, neither does the image appear to be...is this a twitter-bootstrap project?

Comment: No, just a Drupal project with a twitter ShareThis button.

Comment: the style of the image has `display:none` that wont help..

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  The span is no longer displayed as you want, but something else is happening?

Comment: I get your point. I'll approve a solution and ask another question if necessary.

Comment: I think I know what is going on.  When the span doesn't exist, the button collapses/disappears, correct?  In that case, instead of `display: none`, do `width: 0px`. (I wasn't making a point, I truly was just confused).

Comment: I tried, but it does not solve the issue too. I am looking at earlier release code and it really seems like these releases have been made by amateurs... Thanks for your help anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the style of an element with two classes specifically, combine them with no spaces.  The dot notation means "class", so you would put a dot before each of them and concatenate them:

```
span.chicklets.twitter {
    display: none;
}
```

As @AndrewBrock suggested, you can also just use one of the classes, as long as you know that the single class won't affect other span elements in an undesirable manner.

If you need the span to maintain the button, but don't want the span to take up space, then change it to this:

```
span.chicklets.twitter {
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: How did I not get this. Must be because it is 6am here

Answer (score 3):

`chicklets` and `twitter` are 2 separate classes. You only need to set the `display:none` in one of these.

```
span.chicklets {
    display:none;
}
```

I have restricted this to only span elements with the class `chicklets`.
Note that this could affect other span elements which also have the `chicklets` class

Comment: Your code will not affect any other elements with the `chicklets` class. Only spans.

Comment: @Jason - isn't that the goal?

Comment: Of course, I'm commenting on his last statement: "Note that this could affect other elements which also have the chicklets class" which isn't true.

Comment: @Jason i missed the word "span" in there, have fixed it now, thanks

Comment: In fact, it was in a span, but i had the triangle brackets around it, which apparently makes it invisible in markdown

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery running this will do it (remove it versus hide it):

```
$(".chicklets.twitter").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use JQuery on this page.